# What is more efficient in vba for moving in rows in the next tree codes

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have a question what of the  tree next codes is more efficient in VBA

Option 1:

```
While fin 

    if activecell.value = "Comp"
        ' do something 
        ' I use some many time the value of the activecell or the line 
        ' im actually
    end if

    activecell.offset(1,0).activate

loop
```

Option 2:

```
dim i as long
i=0

While fin 

    if activecell.offset(i,0).value = "Comp"
        ' do something 
        ' I use some many time the value of the activecell or the line 
        ' im actually
    end if

    i = i + 1
loop
```

Option 3: 'because I use some many times the actual row I dont know 
        'If maybe is better to take that value to a variable

```
dim i as long
dim x as string
i=0

While fin 

    x = activecell.offset(i,0)

    if x = "Comp"
        ' do something 
        ' I use some many time the value of the activecell or 
        'the line im actually
    end if

    i = i + 1
loop
```

Thanks In advance for your help

PD FOr all the codes I have

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: Have you tried them? What did you find out?

Comment: Hey Yes I tried its faster but I have to practice more with this method at the moment is not natural for me. Thanks So much for your Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 4, i.e. the Option 4 that you didn't write, is much more efficient than your options 1-3. Don't bother activating or offsetting any cells. Just load your data to a Variant array, and operate on that.

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Long

v = Sheet1.Range("A1:A1000").Value ' or wherever your data is

For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    If v(i, 1) = "Comp" Then
        ' do something
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: mmm interesting but I have to use variable arrays because depends of colummn "A" i have to analize the values in columns "B" "C"--- "D"

Answer (score 2):

Option 2.

With Option 1 you are activating the cell on every iteration which is not necessary. Option 3 you are setting to a variable but only using it once and so there is a cost in the setting but no use outside of the initial check.

Also when checking use Value2 as this does not check for Currency / Dates and for a string will be faster than the implicit .Value used currently:

```
if activecell.offset(i,0).Value2 = "Comp"
```

Comment: I forgot to said I have not update in scream and In Option 3 I use X some many time but didnt write the full lines where I use for have a clear code.

Comment: I have another small question whats difference Between Activecell.offset(0,1) and activecell.offset(0,1).value2 because both return the value of the cell.

Comment: as per MSDN: "The only difference between this property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn’t use the Currency and Date data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the Double data type." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa218198(v=office.10).aspx. Hence Value2 is a fraction faster due to this.

Comment: Hey but im not asking about value2 and value My question is about

1.- Activecell.offset(0,1)
2 .- Activecell.offset(0,1).value2

Why (1) returns me the value

Comment: the default property of Activecell.offset(0,1) is Value and so in fact even though its not explicit you are comparing .Value to .Value2